# When would I use IJobProcessComponentData and when IJobParallelFor?

Tags: unity, entity-system

Quick question regarding the Job system in conjunction with pure ECS. When would I use `IJobProcessComponentData` and when `IJobParallelFor`? I can just assume the first one if it is just juggling data from one component to the other akin to `CopyTransformToGameObjectComponent` with possibly some simple thread-safe computations while the latter might be used to handle results of complex computations that have been done outside of the job such raycasts or things referring to actual GameObjects etc.?